# Can't resolve 'crypto' in react-oauth2-pkce

Tags: reactjs

I have a React.js application which is part of an oAuth2 architecture and in order to get a token it uses Authorization Code + PKCE flow as explained [here](https://rmannibucau.metawerx.net/react-oauth2-pkce-flow-setup.html).

The issue is that when I try to run the app `npm start` I get the following error:

[image]

I tried with the suggested approach at many places to add the following in my `package.json` after devDependencies:

```
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
```

but I still have the same issue. I am using Node.js 14.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a big issue, and I will not elaborate on the various moving parts that causes the issue.

What you need to do:

1. run `yarn add crypto-browserify stream-browserify buffer`
2. run `yarn add -D react-app-rewired`
3. create a new file in the root of your directory: **config-overrides.js** with the contents:

   ```
   const webpack = require('webpack');
   module.exports = function override(config, env) {
     config.resolve = config.resolve || {};
     config.resolve.fallback = config.resolve.fallback || {};
     config.resolve.fallback.crypto = require.resolve('crypto-browserify');
     config.resolve.fallback.stream = require.resolve('stream-browserify');
     config.resolve.fallback.buffer = require.resolve("buffer")
     config.resolve.alias.buffer = 'buffer'
     config.plugins = config.plugins || [];
     config.plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],}));
     return config;
   }
   ```
4. Edit your **package.json** and make sure it looks like this:

   ```
   ...
   "scripts": {
     "start": "react-app-rewired start",
     "build": "react-app-rewired build",
     "test": "react-app-rewired test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   },
   ...
   ```
5. run `rm -fr node_modules/.cache`

---

Read more:

- [The actual issue that caused all this - "BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills..." - issue 11756 at CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756)
- [related react-oauth2-pkce issue 33](https://github.com/gardner/react-oauth2-pkce/issues/33)
- [How to re-wire CRA](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#how-to-rewire-your-create-react-app-project)